# Error when trying to install flask-mysql on macOS

Tags: python, mysql, macos, flask

I'm trying to install flask-mysql in a virtual python environment but every time I run `pip3 install flask-mysql`

I get a really long error message:

> Collecting flask-mysqldb
> Using cached Flask_MySQLdb-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
> Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=1.0.4 in ./.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from flask-mysqldb) (3.0.2)
> Collecting mysqlclient>=2.2.0 (from flask-mysqldb)
> Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.4.tar.gz (90 kB)
> Installing build dependencies ... done
> Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
> │ exit code: 1
> ╰─> [27 lines of output]
> Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
> Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 1.
> Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
> Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
> Trying pkg-config --exists libmariadb
> Command 'pkg-config --exists libmariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/aaron/Desktop/Project/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in 
> main()
> File "/Users/aaron/Desktop/Project/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
> json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/aaron/Desktop/Project/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
> return hook(config_settings)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/private/var/folders/lk/l0k2xtg12vs3bchf3_3_yzvw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-8pn8noav/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
> return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/private/var/folders/lk/l0k2xtg12vs3bchf3_3_yzvw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-8pn8noav/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
> self.run_setup()
> File "/private/var/folders/lk/l0k2xtg12vs3bchf3_3_yzvw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-8pn8noav/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
> exec(code, locals())
> File "", line 155, in 
> File "", line 49, in get_config_posix
> File "", line 28, in find_package_name
> Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
> Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
> [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: [Solution]
brew install mysql pkg-config